# Recyler view not iterating over all items, it shows only one item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am tried to display images horrizontally with help of recyler view, but recyler view adapter iterates over only one item even if list size having 3.
I didnnt understand why this is happening. Please help me out.

I have tried with keeping layout_height of recylerview as well as row item layout as wrap_content but not worked.

Row item for image recycler view: item_glance_image_comments.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/img_glanceImagecontent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

item_glance in which recyler view is present

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#e2e2e2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_7sdp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#eb650d"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_glance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">



                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_glancecontent"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter for showing images:

```
class GlanceMainImageContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GlanceMainImageContentAdapter.VideoInfoHolder> implements Filterable {

    Context ctx;
    List<PostContentGlance> data = new ArrayList<>();
    List<PostContentGlance> datalistfilter;

    public GlanceMainImageContentAdapter(Context ctx, List<PostContentGlance> glanceImageContents) {

        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.data = glanceImageContents;
        this.datalistfilter = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VideoInfoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_glance_image_comments, parent, false);
        return new GlanceMainImageContentAdapter.VideoInfoHolder(itemView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GlanceMainImageContentAdapter.VideoInfoHolder holder, int position) {

        PostContentGlance postContentGlance = datalistfilter.get(position);

        int listSize = data.size();
        int pos = position;

        holder.txt_count_images.setText(pos+1+" / "+listSize);


        Glide.with(ctx)
                .load(postContentGlance.getPiImage())
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.user)
                        .fitCenter())
                .into(holder.img_glanceImagecontent);


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datalistfilter.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    datalistfilter = data;
                } else {
                    List<PostContentGlance> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (PostContentGlance row : data) {

                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }

                    datalistfilter = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = datalistfilter;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                datalistfilter = (ArrayList<PostContentGlance>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }




    public class VideoInfoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView img_glanceImagecontent;
        TextView txt_count_images;

        public VideoInfoHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            img_glanceImagecontent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_glanceImagecontent);
            txt_count_images = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_count_images);


        }
    }

}
```

Api response :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "p_id": 105,
            "p_user_id": 2,
            "p_access_id": 1,
            "p_description": "pdf upload demo",
            "p_status": 1,
            "p_created_at": "2019-07-22 18:31:39",
            "p_updated_at": "2019-07-22 18:31:39",
            "p_post_id": null,
            "post_user": {
                "id": 2,
                "first_name": "Anand",
                "last_name": "Deshmukh",
                "profile_image": "http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/users/1564564830.png"
            },
            "post_content": [
                {
                    "pi_id": 65,
                    "pi_post_id": 105,
                    "pi_image": "http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/glance/1563800499.pdf",
                    "pi_file_type": "file"
                }
            ],
            "post_likes": {
                "count": 1,
                "isLike": 0
            },
            "post_shares_count": 0,
            "post_comments": {
                "count": 4,
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "c_id": 53,
                        "c_comment": "hey test",
                        "c_created_at": "2019-07-29T09:02:11.000000Z",
                        "user_id": 2,
                        "user_name": "Anand Deshmukh",
                        "user_image": "http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/users/1564564830.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "c_id": 52,
                        "c_comment": "hi",
                        "c_created_at": "2019-07-29T08:30:06.000000Z",
                        "user_id": 2,
                        "user_name": "Anand Deshmukh",
                        "user_image": "http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/users/1564564830.png"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "user_follow_type": "Unfollow"
        },
        {
            "p_id": 100,
            "p_user_id": 2,
            "p_access_id": 1,
            "p_description": "Base 64 pdf",
            "p_status": 1,
            "p_created_at": "2019-07-22 10:10:04",
            "p_updated_at": "2019-07-22 10:10:04",
            "p_post_id": null,
            "post_user": {
                "id": 2,
                "first_name": "Anand",
                "last_name": "Deshmukh",
                "profile_image": "http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/users/1564564830.png"
            },
            "post_content": [
                {
                    "pi_id": 61,
                    "pi_post_id": 100,
                    "pi_image": "http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/glance/1563770405.pdf",
                    "pi_file_type": "file"
                }
            ],
            "post_likes": {
                "count": 1,
                "isLike": 0
            },
            "post_shares_count": 0,
            "post_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "comments": []
            },
            "user_follow_type": "Unfollow"
        },
        {
            "p_id": 94,
            "p_user_id": 2,
            "p_access_id": 1,
            "p_description": "Base 64",
            "p_status": 1,
            "p_created_at": "2019-07-20 18:09:39",
            "p_updated_at": "2019-07-20 18:09:39",
            "p_post_id": null,
            "post_user": {
                "id": 2,
                "first_name": "Anand",
                "last_name": "Deshmukh",
                "profile_image": "http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/users/1564564830.png"
            },
            "post_content": [
                {
                    "pi_id": 56,
                    "pi_post_id": 94,
                    "pi_image": "http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/glance/1563626379.png",
                    "pi_file_type": "image"
                }
            ],
            "post_likes": {
                "count": 1,
                "isLike": 0
            },
            "post_shares_count": 0,
            "post_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "comments": []
            },
            "user_follow_type": "Unfollow"
        },

        {
            "p_id": 55,
            "p_user_id": 2,
            "p_access_id": 1,
            "p_description": null,
            "p_status": 1,
            "p_created_at": "2019-07-19 11:02:58",
            "p_updated_at": "2019-07-19 11:02:58",
            "p_post_id": null,
            "post_user": {
                "id": 2,
                "first_name": "Anand",
                "last_name": "Deshmukh",
                "profile_image": "http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/users/1564564830.png"
            },
            "post_content": [
                {
                    "pi_id": 45,
                    "pi_post_id": 55,
                    "pi_image": "http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/glance/1563514378.1.jpg",
                    "pi_file_type": "image"
                },
                {
                    "pi_id": 46,
                    "pi_post_id": 55,
                    "pi_image": "http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/glance/1563514378.2.jpg",
                    "pi_file_type": "image"
                },
                {
                    "pi_id": 47,
                    "pi_post_id": 55,
                    "pi_image": "http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/glance/1563514378.3.jpg",
                    "pi_file_type": "image"
                }
            ],
            "post_likes": {
                "count": 0,
                "isLike": 0
            },
            "post_shares_count": 0,
            "post_comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "comments": []
            },
            "user_follow_type": "Unfollow"
        }
}
```

Glance Adapter from recyler view adapter set

```
public class GlanceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    Context ctx;


    //Glance Content
    public GlanceMainImageContentAdapter glanceMainImageContentAdapter;
    List<PostContentGlance> glanceImageContents = new ArrayList<>();
    List<PostContentGlance> glanceImageContentssharepopup = new ArrayList<>();



    public GlanceYoutubeInnerContentAdapter glanceYoutubeInnerContentAdapter;
    public GlanceShareYoutubeInnerContentAdapter glanceShareYoutubeInnerContentAdapter;
    List<YoutubeData> glanceYoutubeInnerContents = new ArrayList<>();


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    String pdfPath = "";

    public GlanceAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, List<DataMultiviewTypeGlance> data) {
        this.ctx = activity;
        this.data = data;
        this.datalistfilter =data;

    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view;
        switch (viewType) {

            case 2:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_glance, parent, false);
                return new GlanceAdapter.VideoInfoHolder2(view);
        }
        return null;

    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holdermain, final int position) {

        sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences("agricos", MODE_PRIVATE);

        final DataMultiviewTypeGlance listmain = datalistfilter.get(position);

        final int duration = 50;
        final int pixelsToMove = 100;
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        switch (holdermain.getItemViewType()) {
            case 1:


            case 2:
                final GlanceAdapter.VideoInfoHolder2 holder = (GlanceAdapter.VideoInfoHolder2)holdermain;

                mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

                final glanceData list = listmain.glanceDataObj;
                final glanceData glanceDataShare =  listmain.glanceDataObj;

                final Boolean[] isClicked = {false};

                if((!(list.getPPostId() == null))){}else {


                    /**************** Start Main Post **********************************************************************/


                    glanceImageContents.clear();
                    glanceImageContents = list.getPostContentGlance();


                    if (glanceImageContents.size() > 0) {
                        if (glanceImageContents.get(0).getPiFileType().equals("image")) {

                            holder.recycler_glancecontent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.layout_videoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.layout_pdfview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.layout_youtubeview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            holder.recycler_glancecontent.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            //to use RecycleView, you need a layout manager. default is LinearLayoutManage
                            CustomLinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(ctx);
                            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(CustomLinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
                            holder.recycler_glancecontent.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                            glanceMainImageContentAdapter = new GlanceMainImageContentAdapter(ctx, glanceImageContents);
                            holder.recycler_glancecontent.setAdapter(glanceMainImageContentAdapter);
                            holder.recycler_glancecontent.scheduleLayoutAnimation();


                        } else if (list.getPostContentGlance().get(0).getPiFileType().equals("video")) {
                            holder.recycler_glancecontent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.layout_pdfview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.layout_videoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.txt_video_description.setText(list.getPDescription());
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse(list.getPostContentGlance().get(0).getPiImage()); //Declare your url here.

                            holder.videoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(ctx));
                            holder.videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
                            holder.videoview.requestFocus();
                            // holder.videoview.start();
                        } else if (list.getPostContentGlance().get(0).getPiFileType().equals("file")) {


                            holder.recycler_glancecontent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.layout_videoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.layout_pdfview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.txt_pdf_description.setText(list.getPDescription());

                            // http://ag.homeplanetary.com/uploads/glance/1563800499.pdf
                            String[] pdfnameArray = list.getPostContentGlance().get(0).getPiImage().split("/");
                            int length = pdfnameArray.length;
                            String pdfname = pdfnameArray[length - 1];

                            holder.txt_pdf_view.setText(pdfname);

                            pdfPath = "";
                            pdfPath = list.getPostContentGlance().get(0).getPiImage();
                        }


                    }

                }
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        switch (datalistfilter.get(position).getType()) {
            case 1:
                return datalistfilter.get(position).getType();
            case 2:
                return datalistfilter.get(position).getType();

            default:
                return -1;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datalistfilter.size();
    }

    public class VideoInfoHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txt_glanceusername,txt_glancedate,txt_glancelike,txt_glancecomment,
                txt_glanceshare;

        ImageView user_glanceprofileimg,img_glancelike,img_glancecomment
                ,img_glanceshare,img_loggedInUser;

        LinearLayout layout_comment,layout_glance,layout_sharedpost,layout_comment_shared;
        EditText etx_glancecomment,etx_glancecomment_shared;
        VideoView videoview;
        LinearLayout layout_videoview,layout_youtubeview;
        TextView txt_video_description,txt_video_youtube;

        RecyclerView recycler_glanceyoutubecontent;

        ImageView user_glanceprofileimg_shared,user_glanceprofileimg_shared_in
                ,img_glancelike_shared_in,img_glancelike_shared,img_glancecomment_shared,img_glanceshare_shared
                ,img_loggedInUser_shared;
        TextView txt_glanceusername_shared,txt_glancedate_shared,txt_glanceusername_shared_in
                ,txt_glancedate_shared_in,txt_glancelike_shared_in,txt_glancelike_shared,txt_glancecomment_shared,txt_glanceshare_shared;

        RecyclerView recycler_glancecomments,recycler_glancecontent,recycler_glancecomments_shared
                ,recycler_glancecomments_more,recycler_glancecomments_more_share;

        RecyclerView recycler_glancecontent_shared_in,recycler_glanceyoutubecontent_shared_in;
        LinearLayout layout_videoview_shared_in,layout_youtubeview_shared_in,layout_pdfview,layout_pdfview_shared;
        TextView txt_video_description_shared_in,txt_video_youtube_shared_in;
        VideoView videoview_shared_in;
        Button btn_loadmorecomments,btn_loadmorecomments_share;
        TextView txt_pdf_description,txt_pdf_view,txt_pdf_description_shared,txt_pdf_view_shared;

        TextView txt_time_glance_shared_in,txt_time_glance_shared,txt_time_glance
                ,img_glancemenu_shared,img_glancemenu,img_glancecommentsend,img_glancecommentsend_shared;




        public VideoInfoHolder2(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            txt_time_glance_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_glance_shared_in);
            txt_time_glance_shared_in.setTypeface(FontAwesomeManager.getTypeface(ctx, FontAwesomeManager.FONTAWESOME));
            txt_time_glance_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_glance_shared);
            txt_time_glance_shared.setTypeface(FontAwesomeManager.getTypeface(ctx, FontAwesomeManager.FONTAWESOME));
            txt_time_glance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_glance);
            txt_time_glance.setTypeface(FontAwesomeManager.getTypeface(ctx, FontAwesomeManager.FONTAWESOME));

            layout_glance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_glance);

            //Shared
            user_glanceprofileimg_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_glanceprofileimg_shared);
            img_glancemenu_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_glancemenu_shared);
            img_glancemenu_shared.setTypeface(FontAwesomeManager.getTypeface(ctx, FontAwesomeManager.FONTAWESOME));
            user_glanceprofileimg_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_glanceprofileimg_shared_in);
            img_glancelike_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_glancelike_shared_in);
            img_glancelike_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_glancelike_shared);

            img_glancecomment_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_glancecomment_shared);
            img_glanceshare_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_glanceshare_shared);
            txt_glanceusername_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glanceusername_shared);
            txt_glancedate_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glancedate_shared);
            txt_glanceusername_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glanceusername_shared_in);
            txt_glancedate_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glancedate_shared_in);
            txt_glancelike_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glancelike_shared_in);
            txt_glancelike_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glancelike_shared);
            txt_glancecomment_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glancecomment_shared);
            txt_glanceshare_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glanceshare_shared);

            etx_glancecomment_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etx_glancecomment_shared);
            layout_sharedpost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_sharedpost);
            layout_comment_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_comment_shared);
            img_loggedInUser_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_loggedInUser_shared);
            img_glancecommentsend_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_glancecommentsend_shared);
            img_glancecommentsend_shared.setTypeface(FontAwesomeManager.getTypeface(ctx, FontAwesomeManager.FONTAWESOME));
            recycler_glancecomments_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_glancecomments_shared);

            //main
            txt_glanceusername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glanceusername);
            user_glanceprofileimg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_glanceprofileimg);
            txt_glancedate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glancedate);
            img_glancemenu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_glancemenu);
            img_glancemenu.setTypeface(FontAwesomeManager.getTypeface(ctx, FontAwesomeManager.FONTAWESOME));
            img_glancelike = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_glancelike);

            txt_glancelike = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glancelike);
            img_glancecomment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_glancecomment);
            txt_glancecomment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glancecomment);
            img_glanceshare = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_glanceshare);
            txt_glanceshare = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_glanceshare);
            layout_comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_comment);

            img_loggedInUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_loggedInUser);
            etx_glancecomment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etx_glancecomment);
            img_glancecommentsend = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_glancecommentsend);
            img_glancecommentsend.setTypeface(FontAwesomeManager.getTypeface(ctx, FontAwesomeManager.FONTAWESOME));

            videoview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
            layout_videoview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_videoview);
            txt_video_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_video_description);

            recycler_glancecomments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_glancecomments);
            recycler_glancecontent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_glancecontent);
            layout_youtubeview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_youtubeview);
            txt_video_youtube = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_video_youtube);

            recycler_glanceyoutubecontent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_glanceyoutubecontent);

            recycler_glancecontent_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_glancecontent_shared_in);
            recycler_glanceyoutubecontent_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_glanceyoutubecontent_shared_in);
            layout_videoview_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_videoview_shared_in);
            layout_youtubeview_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_youtubeview_shared_in);
            txt_video_description_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_video_description_shared_in);
            txt_video_youtube_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_video_youtube_shared_in);
            videoview_shared_in = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoview_shared_in);

            recycler_glancecomments_more = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_glancecomments_more);
            recycler_glancecomments_more_share = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_glancecomments_more_share);
            btn_loadmorecomments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_loadmorecomments);
            btn_loadmorecomments_share = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_loadmorecomments_share);

            layout_pdfview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_pdfview);
            txt_pdf_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_pdf_description);
            txt_pdf_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_pdf_view);

            layout_pdfview_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_pdfview_shared);
            txt_pdf_description_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_pdf_description_shared);
            txt_pdf_view_shared = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_pdf_view_shared);


        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Please help me out.Thanks

Comment: Please add `fragment/activity.xml` where you have used `recycleview`.

Comment: In api responce you have only 1 item

Comment: First of all, show us what you have tried, and I mean an actual `code` and not just the layout.

Also for `I am trying to display images horizontally` - use `ViewPage2` for that

Answer (score 0):

> I am tried to display images **horizontally** with help of recyler view,
>   but recyler view adapter iterates over only one item even if list size
>   having 3. I didnnt understand why this is happening. Please help me
>   out.
>
> I have tried with keeping **layout_height** of recylerview as well as row
>   item layout as **wrap_content** but not worked.

If you will work horizontally, then set *layout_width* of RecyclerView to *wrap_content*, not *layout_height*.

Also you need to set RecyclerView horizontal

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: @SatishGodse and if you make it vertical, then it works?

Comment: No for vertical also not works. It works only if there is only one image in response

Comment: and if there 2 images, nothing showing? Try to scroll down or on side. If still not works, try to set width and height to wrap_content in item and for RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Please set orientation of layout manager horizantal, not vertical.

LinearLayoutManager  mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);

Comment: yes, I have alredy tried with horrizontal but not worked yet.

Comment: Please put the image view width and hight static like 250dp for testing and try. If not worked please post the code of Activity.

Comment: not worked. code hirechy like this : HomePageActivity >> GlanceFragment >> Glance Adapter >> GlanceMainImageContentAdapter .    horrizontal images show recyler view is on glance adapter screen i.e item_glance.  I have put all files in que content. please check it.

Comment: why you set visibility = gone in below layout
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_glancecontent"/>

Comment: In response there were 3 type of data images, videos and documents . Until I have not used multiview type recyler view so I managing 2 recyler views for the content